# Storyboard Add NavigaitonController Unable to display title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLRh6.jpg)

I haven't started to write the code yet

But，Unable to display the headline of the `UINavigationBar` after running

No change of property

Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)，I hope to help me

Comment: In your viewcontroller set self.title = "Test"

Answer (score 0):

if you are in NavigationController you can access the title like :

```
self.title = "New Title"
```

else if you are'nt in NavigationController but you have UINavigationBar you can access the title like :

```
@IBOutlet weak var NavBar: UINavigationBar!
self.navBar.topItem?.title = "MyNewTitle"
```